# java cannot find symbol error

Tags: java

I have a simple file system, in which all the files being used by the main program are in the same folder. The main program is also in the same system. It was actually a jar file by my friend and then I unzipped it using winrar, the class files are running well, but only when i amended something and tried to compile the program i am getting this error of cannot find symbol for one of the class being used, and its right there in the same folder. How can i resolve this please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are there any package declarations in your source files?

Comment: @Howard yes there are but, I just want to compile it first.And all the files including main program comes under package next;

Comment: It's going to be tough for us to help you without any actual code.

Comment: Then first put your source files in appropriate subfolders (with the same name as your packages, in this case `next`). Then compile from the root using `javac next/*.java`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to place your source files into appropriate subfolders. The name of the folder corresponds to your package name, in this case `next`.

```
next/Pretty.java
next/Tree.java
...
```

Then you can compile using command

```
javac next/*.java
```

from the base directory.